# when I try to pop from a queue it doesn't pop why?

Tags: c++11

I have the following code but the pop() function doesn't work I don't
know why.

```
#include < iostream >
#include < fstream >
#include < sstream >
#include < string >
#include < queue >

    using namespace std;
int quantum;
struct process {
    string name;
    int arrival;
    int burst;
    int priority;
};

process parseProcess(string s)
    //parse the given string s to find the process information
    {
        process p;
        stringstream lineStream;
        lineStream.str(s);
        string item;
        getline(lineStream, item, '$');
        p.name = item;
        getline(lineStream, item, '$');
        p.arrival = stoi(item);
        getline(lineStream, item, '$');
        p.burst = stoi(item);
        getline(lineStream, item, '$');
        p.priority = stoi(item);
        cout <<
            p.name << "\t" << p.arrival << "\t" << p.burst << "\t" << p.priority << "\t" << endl;
        return p;
    }
void second_write(queue < process > s, int n, int quantum) {
    int * burst_Time = new int[n], total = 0,
        total_turn_arround = 0;
    float avgwaiting_time = 0, avgturn_arround =
        0;
    int * remaining_burst_time = new int[n];
    int * waitting_time = new
    int[n];
    int * turn_arround_time = new int[n]; //now queue doesn't pop
    Why ? ? ? ? ? process temp = s.front();
    process p;
    queue < process > qtemp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p.name = temp.name;
        p.arrival = temp.arrival;
        p.burst = temp.burst;
        burst_Time[i] = p.burst;
        p.priority = temp.priority; * * s.pop(); * * qtemp.push(p);
        cout
            << temp.name << "\t" << temp.arrival << "\t" << temp.burst << "\t" <<
            temp.priority << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        remaining_burst_time[i] = burst_Time[i];

    }
    while (1) {
        bool finished = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (remaining_burst_time[i] > 0) {
                finished = false;
                if (remaining_burst_time[i] > quantum) {
                    total += quantum;
                    remaining_burst_time[i] -= quantum;
                } else {
                    total += remaining_burst_time[i];
                    waitting_time[i] = total - burst_Time[i];
                    remaining_burst_time[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        if (finished == true) break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        turn_arround_time[i] = burst_Time[i] - waitting_time[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        total += waitting_time[i];
        total_turn_arround += turn_arround_time[i];
    }
    avgturn_arround =
        total_turn_arround / n;
    avgwaiting_time = total / n;
    int w = 0;
    while (!qtemp.empty()) {
        process temp2 = qtemp.front();
        qtemp.pop();
    }

}

int main() //it takes two arguments 1:inputFile name,
2: outputFile name {
    string fileName;
    cout << "enter file name " <<
        endl;
    cin >> fileName;
    cout << "Enter quantum";
    cin >> quantum;
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string line;
    queue < process > q;
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        process p = parseProcess(line);
        q.push(p);
    }
    int Length = q.size();
    second_write(q, Length, quantum);

    /*Your code must be written here in order to sort the processes in
the queue in terms of the chosen cpu scheduling algorithm.     Your code
also needs to calcualte average wating time and average turnarround
time.     Finally your code needs to print the Gantt chart, waiting time
for each process and the average waiting time and the average
turnaround time on the screen     */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the first i post a question sry for that but s.pop() doesn't work

Comment: Please format your code properly. I would but it's too cluttered for me.

Comment: I ran your code through a pretty printer, please review it to see that I didn't mangle it too badly in the process.

Comment: What makes you believe `s.pop()` doesn't work? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ? One thing I notice is that, while you call `pop()` in a loop, you only call `front()` once. You print the same `process` element `n` times - the one that was first in the queue when `second_write` was called. Similarly, you push the same element into `qtemp` over and over.